# Check if list of keys exist in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like that:

```
grades = {
        'alex' : 11,
        'bob'  : 10,
        'john' : 14,
        'peter': 7
       }
```

and a list of names `students = ('alex', 'john')`

I need to check that all the names in `students` exist as keys in `grades` dict.

`grades` can have more names, but all the names in `students` should be in `grades`

There must be a straightforward way to do it, but i'm still new to python and can't figure it out. tried `if students in grades`, didn't work.

In the actual cases, the lists will be much bigger.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(name in grades for name in students):
    # whatever
```

Comment: Great! Any shortcut way to get the elements that are missing from the dic if the condition is False?

Comment: @guival Yup, you can use set operations, e.g. `set(students) - grades.keys()` in Python 3.

Comment: is there a way to check if any of a list of keys is a sub string in a string?

Comment: @Jonathan Not sure what you mean, maybe `any(k in my_string for k in keys)`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach just discovered any()! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: This is offtopic, but why do "all" and generator expression share a parenthesis? If we remove all() casting, generator is invalid, due to missing parenthesis...

Comment: @yomajo It's just how Python's grammer is defined. Generator expressions need to be in parens, but the parens of a single-argument function call will do. If you pass a generator expression to a function with two arguments, you need an additional pair of parens.

Answer (score 31):

```
>>> grades = {
        'alex' : 11,
        'bob'  : 10,
        'john' : 14,
        'peter': 7
}
>>> names = ('alex', 'john')
>>> set(names).issubset(grades)
True
>>> names = ('ben', 'tom')
>>> set(names).issubset(grades)
False
```

Calling it `class` is invalid so I changed it to `names`.

Comment: This can't short-cut, in contrast to `all()`.  It will always be O(m+n), where m and n are the respective sizes of `names` and `grades`.  Using `all()` will be O(m), and might short-cut.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Right, I'll just leave it here since it is another approach but I agree that yours is the best.

Comment: Definitely leave it here!  It's an interesting approach in any case.

Answer (score 9):

You can test if a number of keys are in a dict by taking advantage that `<dict>.keys()` returns a `set`.

This logic in code...

```
if 'foo' in d and 'bar' in d and 'baz' in d:
    do_something()
```

can be represented more briefly as:

```
if {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'} <= d.keys():
    do_something()
```

The `<=` operator for sets tests for whether the set on the left is a subset of the set on the right. Another way of writing this would be `<set>.issubset(other)`.

There are other interesting operations supported by sets: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set

Using this trick can condense a lot of places in code that check for several keys as shown in the first example above.

Whole lists of keys could also be checked for using `<=`:

```
if set(students) <= grades.keys():
    print("All studends listed have grades in your class.")

# or using unpacking - which is actually faster than using set()
if {*students} <= grades.keys():
    ...
```

Or if `students` is also a dict:

```
if students.keys() <= grades.keys():
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming students as set

```
if not (students - grades.keys()):
    print("All keys exist")
```

If not convert it to set

```
if not (set(students) - grades.keys()):
    print("All keys exist")
```