# Function to check if N number of keys exist in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking to create a function that will check if multiple keys are present in a dictionary and return a value that indicates which keys were present. I know I could write something like:

```
def param_checker(parameters):
    if 'foo' in parameters:
        if 'bar' in parameters:
            if 'qux' in parameters:
                return 0
            else:
                return 1
        elif 'baz' in parameters:
            if 'qux' in parameters:
                return 2
            else:
                return 3
        else:
            return 4
    elif 'quxx' in parameters:
        if 'bar' in parameters:
            return 5
        elif 'qux' in parameters:
            if 'baz' in parameters:
                return 6
            else:
                return 7
        else:
            return 8
    else:
        return 9
```

However, the above example is both messy and clunky. The complexity also scales with the number of parameters you need to check to return a value. For example, I needed 3 layers of `if` conditions to check the keys `foo`, `bar`, and `qux`. I know I could chain the `if` conditions inline, but it is still messy and clunky.

This is somewhat similar to [Python check if list of keys exist in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995172/python-check-if-list-of-keys-exist-in-dictionary). The big difference here is that instead of checking if they all exist or not, I am looking to return a value indicating what combination of keys exist.

*Note: I did not write out all possible combinations in the provided sample code, as that would be tedious when I am just trying to illustrate the problem.*

Below is a example of invoking the function to check which keys are present.

```
d = dict()
d['foo'] = 'blah'
d['bar'] = 'blah'

val = param_checker(d)
# val represents a unique value indicating which keys are present in dictionary d
```

I will know ahead of time what keys *could* be in the dictionary, so I can have some sort of list of possible keys, like:

```
keys = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quxx"]
```

I am hoping to build a function that can check `N` keys and return a unique value indicating which ones where present. How can I efficiently do this?

Comment: Please post a sample of your input and your desired output.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
The posted code merely defines a function and quits.

Comment: Why are you hard coding the values? Is it just for sample here or is that actually what you are using?

Comment: This isn't just an implementation problem. The semantics of this function are also extremely confusing. Why do some values not matter when certain other values are found? Why 5 and not 6 for some particular case? What's the meaning of all this?

Comment: Suppose we can easily find the subset of a set of keys `["foo", "bar", "qux", "baz", "quxx"]` that is in a dictionary (we can) ... that what is your rule for mapping that subset to a number?

Comment: @user2357112 I did not go through all possible combinations of keys `["foo", "bar", "qux", "baz", "quxx"]`. Also, the value `5` or `6` is just some unique value that can be used to indicate which combination of keys was present in `parameters`

Comment: @donkopotamus I am looking for a unique return value. In this sample code, each number is for a unique combination. The sample code is also just to illustrate the problem pace. If the unique return values is a number or a hash or something else, that can also work. It just need to uniquely identify the combination of keys that were present.

Comment: @theBrainyGeek This is just sample code to illustrate the problem. I would not want to hard code values in a structure like this in the full function checking `N` keys. That would be a nightmare.

Comment: @Ajax1234 added some sample code illustrates a sample usage scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keyseq = ('foo', 'bar', 'quux')
keymap = {key: 1 << e for (e, key) in enumerate(keyseq)}
return sum(keymap[key] for key in keymap if key in D)
```

Comment: The OP also has `qux` and `baz` as keys

Comment: @donkopotamus: The OP can have as many keys as they like as long as they add them to `keyseq`.

Comment: @donkopotamus: The *code* doesn't map, but the eventual question is "I am hoping to build a function that can check N keys and return a unique value indicating which ones where present. How can I efficiently do this?", and that it *does* map to.

Comment: Except that I believe that as it currently stands that mapping is not a binary shift

Comment: @donkopotamus: Each of the N keys can either be present or not. That by definition does lend itself to a binary mapping.

Comment: In the example code whether `quxx` exists *does not matter at all* if `foo` exists ... equally whether `baz` exists does not influence the result of `bar` exists.

Comment: @donkopotamus: I blame that on the OP being tired of writing out all 2**N possibilities.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yup. I did not write out all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (assuming Python 3)?

```
from itertools import compress

queries = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
in_dict = [q in d for q in queries]
existing_keys = compress(queries, in_dict)
```

You can of course wrap this in a function where `queries` become the input parameter and `d` is the input dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Make a set of your desired keys.
Make a set of the dict's keys.
Take the intersection.  Count.

```
master = {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 5,
    "qux": 18,
    "lemon": -6,
    "quxx": "How boring are examples?",
    "dog": False
}

tag = {
    "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quxx"
}

master_set = set(master.keys())
found =  master_set.intersection(tag)

print (len(found), found)
```

Output:

```
4 {'quxx', 'foo', 'qux', 'bar'}
```

Comment: In python 3 you could also just use `master.keys() & tag`

Comment: Right; not specified, so I took the generic way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
keys = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quxx"]
counter = {i:d.keys().count(i) for i in keys}
```