# How to identify if certain keys are present in dictonary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictonary named as Entity which look like this:

```
Entity = {'ORG': 'ABC','PERSON': 'Ankit','ORDINAL': '150th','DATE': 'quarterly', 'MONEY': 'dollars'}
```

Now I have to create other dictionary which will contain below value according to condition.

```
Class = {'Signal':'<Condition>'}
```

The condition is:

- If Entity key consists of ORG and PERSON then in Class dictionary value "Medium" should be updated.
- If Entity key consists of ORG, PERSON, and MONEY then in Class dictionary value "Strong" should be updated.
- If Entity key doesn't consist of above keys then in Class dictionary value "Weak" should be updated.

How should I make the condition for the above problem?

I want an output in Class dictionary like below,

If in Entity dictionary there are ORG and PERSIN keys then Class dictionary should be like,

```
Class = {'Signal' : 'Medium'}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python check if list of keys exist in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995172/python-check-if-list-of-keys-exist-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if all([a in Entity for a in ('ORG', 'PERSON', 'MONEY')]):
    Class['Signal'] = 'strong'
elif all([a in Entity for a in ('ORG', 'PERSON')]):
    Class['Signal'] = 'middle'
elif not any([a in Entity for a in ('ORG', 'PERSON', 'MONEY')]):
    Class['Signal'] = 'weak'
```

Note that, according to your question, if `Entity` contains only `'ORG'` or only `'PERSON'`, no `'Signal'` will be set in `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

To check if dictionary contains specific key use:
`'ORG' in Entity` statement which returns `True` if given key is present in the dictionary and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.keys()` function on the dictionary to check before accessing the data structure. For example:

```
def does_key_exist(elem, dict):
    return elem in dict.keys()
```